# Need to run services with a script in a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I don't have any Dockerfile, I took a fresh centos image and Installed all my services into the container and committed the Docker image. Now I want to start all the service when I will run my conatainer. I have a start-up shell script.

It is not possible to write a Dockerfile, as because there are lot of complex configuration during the installation process.

Comment: Have a look at the `--change` option of `docker commit`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the configuration?  Dockerfiles are pretty fundamental to Docker; the path you describe is an unusual and difficult way to use Docker that will be hard to update later.

Comment: @DavidMaze Like During installation User needs to provide Username and Password. also I need to change manually some configuration files etc.